# Как запросить подтверждение на сохранение файла при закрытии приложения?

Tags: java

При создании приложения с `JFrame` можно задать операцию на закрытие по умолчанию командой

```
  setDefaultCloseOperation(числовая константа)
```

Можно ли как-то вызвать `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(...)` при нажатии на "крестик"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Really close now?", "Close confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (answer == 0) {
                // TODO дописать сохранение несохранённых файлов перед этой строкой
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        }
    });
```